# PencilKit toolPicker is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pencilkit

I am trying to create an app using PencilKit. I have the following code in one of my ViewControllers.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    guard
        let window = view.window,
        let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.shared(for: window) else { return }

    toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
    toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
    canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Although I am calling the `setVisible` function and making the `canvasView` the firstResponder, my `toolPicker` is not showing up, and printing `toolPicker.isVisible` is false.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63034262/5821989

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to `viewWillAppear()`, this did it for me.

Apple is also doing it. I recommend to download and play with the [Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/drawing_with_pencilkit) provided by Apple.